# How to define a default TabView in nativescript?

Tags: javascript, angular, nativescript, angular2-nativescript, nativescript-angular

I created a new nativescript project using the CLI and selected the "tab navigation". I now have the default 3 tabs and I can't find how can I make the default/selected tab to be the rightmost/center tab.

I already tried to move the tabs around by it is always the leftmost that get loaded first.

```
<TabView androidTabsPosition="bottom">

    <page-router-outlet
        *tabItem="{title: 'Home', iconSource: getIconSource('home')}"
        name="homeTab">
    </page-router-outlet>

    <page-router-outlet
        *tabItem="{title: 'Browse', iconSource: getIconSource('browse')}"
        name="browseTab">
    </page-router-outlet>

    <page-router-outlet
        *tabItem="{title: 'Search', iconSource: getIconSource('search')}"
        name="searchTab">
    </page-router-outlet>

</TabView>
```

Answer (score 1):

try this

```
<TabView  [(ngModel)]="tabSelectedIndex"  androidTabsPosition="bottom">

    <page-router-outlet
        *tabItem="{title: 'Home', iconSource: getIconSource('home')}"
        name="homeTab">
    </page-router-outlet>

    <page-router-outlet
        *tabItem="{title: 'Browse', iconSource: getIconSource('browse')}"
        name="browseTab">
    </page-router-outlet>

    <page-router-outlet
        *tabItem="{title: 'Search', iconSource: getIconSource('search')}"
        name="searchTab">
    </page-router-outlet>

</TabView>
```

and in your ts file:

```
 public tabSelectedIndex: number=1; //for example
```

hope it helps.

Answer (score 0):

Use this Code.

**1. app.component.html:-**

```
 <TabView  [(ngModel)]="tabSelectedIndex"  androidTabsPosition="bottom">

 <page-router-outlet
    *tabItem="{title: 'Home', iconSource: getIconSource('home')}"
    name="homeTab">
 </page-router-outlet>

 <page-router-outlet
    *tabItem="{title: 'Browse', iconSource: getIconSource('browse')}"
    name="browseTab">
 </page-router-outlet>

 <page-router-outlet
    *tabItem="{title: 'Search', iconSource: getIconSource('search')}"
    name="searchTab">
 </page-router-outlet>

</TabView>
```

2. **app-routing.module.ts:-**

```
import { NgModule } from "@angular/core";
import { Routes } from "@angular/router";
import { NSEmptyOutletComponent } from "nativescript-angular";
import { NativeScriptRouterModule } from "nativescript-angular/router";

const routes: Routes = [
{
    path: "",
    redirectTo: "/(homeTab:home/default//browseTab:browse/default//searchTab:search/default)",
    pathMatch: "full"
},
{
    path: "home",
    component: NSEmptyOutletComponent,
    loadChildren: "~/app/home/home.module#HomeModule",
    outlet: "homeTab"
},
{
    path: "browse",
    component: NSEmptyOutletComponent,
    loadChildren: "~/app/browse/browse.module#BrowseModule",
    outlet: "browseTab"
},
{
    path: "search",
    component: NSEmptyOutletComponent,
    loadChildren: "~/app/search/search.module#SearchModule",
    outlet: "searchTab"
}
];

@NgModule({
imports: [NativeScriptRouterModule.forRoot(routes)],
exports: [NativeScriptRouterModule]
})
export class AppRoutingModule { }
```